# Erro ao tentar criar novo campo em um model no Django

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, django, django-rest-framework

Ao tentar criar um novo campo em um model durante a criação de uma api, recebo o seguinte erro quando executo o comando `runserver`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa seria a classe:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    teste =  models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=100, default='')
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Tentei rodar o `python manage.py runserver`, inicialmente, também tentei rodar o `makemigrations`. Acredito que esse erro seja relacionado ao SQL Server, mas não ficou claro o por que de ter ocorrido. Mesmo preenchendo o campo `fields` no `serializer`, o erro ocorre.

Comment: Depois de rodar o 'python manage.py makemigrations', você rodou o 'python manage.py migrate'?

Comment: Sim, rodei o migrate, porém o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito difícil dizer logo de cara o que é, pode ser uma configuração/permissão do seu SQL server.

Se você estiver com algum prazo para entrega, recomendo criar o campo via SQL, depois rode um migration "fake", para o django dar o campo como criado.

Isole a migration do campo que você quer criar, em um arquivo de migrations. Depois rode um comando `python manage.py migrate seuapp numero_da_migration --fake`

Ex: `python manage.py migrate venda 0001 --fake`

Outra dica seria pegar o SQL da migration e executar diretamente, ser ser via django. Daí você teria um erro mais detalhado. Pra pegar o SQL da migration siga esse tutorial:

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-show-sql-query-command-in-django-migration/

Comment: Obrigado! Sua resposta conseguiu me ajudar, consegui executar ter acesso aos detalhes do erro e resolvi meu problema.